# Running 64 bit programs on a 32 bit system

Tags: windows, windows-10, 64-bit, 32-bit

As the title says, is there a way of running a x64 bit *program* on a 32 bit *system* ? If not, is there an emulator or is there a way of upgrading from 32 bit to 64 bit for free?  NOTE: I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is one way. You can use [Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) or a similar emulator to **emulate a complete 64 bit host**. However this will come with a **significant** speed loss.

And just to stress that last part a bit:

- Running a hypervisor to run a 32 bit VM on a 64 bit host will let most programs run at almost full speed.  (Long long ago I tested and reached 99% speed of the host using vmware workstation 5 and dnetc, which is a typical user space program.)
- Now if you are going to emulate then expect numbers to be the other way around. 99% speed loss would not be surprising.

So, as an answer to part 1: Technically yes.  You might not want to though.

> or is there a way of upgrading from x32 bit to x64 bit for free.

If your computer has 64 bit hardware (basically everything from the last decade) then you can install a 64 bit OS. DavidPostill's answer is extremely complete on that. Note that this means a full reinstallation. You can not change the windows OS from 32 bit to 64 bit. You will have to completely replace it.

<sup>Not associated with qemu. It is just the one I first remembered</sup>

As pointed out by  Ismael Miguel: As long as your hardware is 64 bit you can use VirtualBox to run a 64 bit OS. Even if you host OS is 32 bit. The documentation for that can be found [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests).

Comment: I didn't even bother proposing an emulator (because of the 99% speed loss) but it's good to have an alternate answer.

Comment: Aye. I am a usually a precise enough person and it is technically possible. So the answer was a 'technically yes'. But I suspect it would be quite non-trivial and locating another computer or reinstalling is probably the practical way to go.

Comment: You don't need QEMU for that. You can run it on VirtualBox. As long as you have a 64bit OS installed (**DON'T FORGET TO SELECT A 64BIT OS**)

Comment: I have no experience with VirtualBox. I'll add the relevant link (https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

Comment: I have experience. I had to test a few Windows installation disks on an old Windows XP, and VirtualBox did the trick to test 64bit installs.

Answer (score 23):

#### Is there a way of running a x64 bit program on a x32 bit system?

You cannot (normally) run 64 bit programs on a 32 bit OS.

See the other answer by [Hennes](https://superuser.com/users/121352/hennes) for a (not recommended) workaround.

---

#### Is there a way of upgrading from x32 bit to x64 bit for free (Windows 10)?

> **Is Your PC 64-bit Capable?**
>
> First thing’s first, you’ll need to confirm whether the CPU in your
>   computer is 64-bit capable. To do so, open the Settings app from your
>   Start menu, select System, and select About. Look to the right of
>   “System type.”
>
> If you see “32-bit operating system, x64-based processor,” this means
>   you’re using a 32-bit version of Windows 10 but your CPU can run a
>   64-bit version. If it doesn’t say you have an x64-based processor, you
>   have a 32-bit CPU and can’t upgrade to the 64-bit version.
>
> [image]
>
> **Does Your CPU Have the Required Features?**
>
> Some of the first 64-bit CPUs don’t have the required features to run
>   64-bit versions of Windows 10, even if they are 64-bit compatible.
>   Specifically, Windows 10 requires PAE, SSE2, and NX. Microsoft has
>   more information about this [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn482072.aspx). PCs will also need support for
>   [CMPXCHG16b](http://cmpxchg16b/), which some of the first consumer 64-bit processors didn’t
>   include.
>
> The 64-bit version of Windows 10 will refuse to install if your CPU
>   doesn’t support these things. If you’d like to check before you begin
>   the install process, download and run [CPU Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html).
>
> “SSE2” will appear under Instructions if it’s supported. “EM64T” or
>   “AMD64” should indicate that PAE is supported. “VT-x” or “[VT-d](http://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/)” always
>   indicates that NX is supported.
>
> [image]
>
> On some older computers, you may have to enable NX (sometimes called
>   XD) in the computer’s BIOS. If you receive an error about your CPU not
>   being supported during the install process, [visit your computer’s
>   BIOS](http://www.howtogeek.com/129815/beginner-geek-how-to-change-the-boot-order-in-your-computers-bios/) and look for an option titled something like “No eXecute bit
>   (NX)”, “eXecute Disabled (XD)”, “No Execute Memory Protect”, “Execute
>   Disabled Memory Protection”, “EDB (Execute Disabled Bit)”, “EVP
>   (Enhanced Virus Protection)”, or something similar. Look under the
>   “Security” or “Advanced” tabs somewhere in your BIOS for this setting.
>
> **Does Your PC’s Hardware Offer 64-bit Drivers?**
>
> Even if your CPU and motherboard support the correct features, you
>   might want to consider whether your computer’s hardware will work
>   properly with a 64-bit version of Windows. 64-bit versions of Windows
>   require 64-bit hardware drivers, and the 32-bit versions you’re using
>   on your current Windows 10 system won’t work.
>
> Modern hardware should certainly offer 64-bit drivers, but very old
>   hardware may no longer be supported and the manufacturer may have
>   never offered 64-bit drivers. To check for this, you can visit the
>   manufacturer’s driver download web pages for your hardware and see if
>   64-bit drivers are available. You shouldn’t necessarily need to
>   download these from the manufacturer’s website — they should be
>   included with Windows 10 or automatically downloaded from Windows
>   Update. But old hardware — for example, a particularly ancient printer
>   — may not offer 64-bit drivers.
>
> Either way, you can find out for sure by installing the 64-bit
>   versions of Windows. if it doesn’t support your CPU, it will let you
>   know. If hardware drivers aren’t available, you’ll see after
>   installing it and you can downgrade to the 32-bit version of Windows
>   10 if your hardware doesn’t work.
>
> **Do the Clean Install**
>
> You’ll need to perform a [clean install](http://www.howtogeek.com/224342/how-to-clean-install-windows-10/) to get to the 64-bit
>   version of Windows 10 from the 32-bit one. There’s no upgrade path.
>
> Warning: [Back up your important files](http://www.howtogeek.com/189452/8-backup-tools-explained-for-windows-7-and-8/) before continuing. This
>   process will wipe your installed programs and files.
>
> First, if you haven’t upgraded to Windows 10 yet, you’ll need to use
>   the upgrade tool to upgrade. You’ll get the 32-bit version of Windows
>   10 if you were previously using a 32-bit version of Windows 7 or 8.1.
>   But the upgrade process will give your PC a Windows 10 license. Be
>   sure to check that your current 32-bit version of Windows 10 is
>   activated under Settings > Update & security > Activation.
>
> [image]
>
> Once you’re already using an activated version of Windows 10,
>   [download the Windows 10 media creation tool from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). If
>   you’re using the 32-bit version of Windows 10 at the moment, you’ll
>   have to download and run the 32-bit tool.
>
> Select “Create installation media for another PC” and use the tool to
>   create a USB drive or burn a disc with Windows 10. As you click
>   through the wizard, you’ll be asked whether you want to create 32-bit
>   or 64-bit installation media. Select the 64-bit architecture.
>
> [image]
>
> Next, reboot your computer and boot from the installation media.
>   Install Windows 10, selecting “Custom install” and overwriting your
>   current version of Windows. When you’re asked to insert a product key,
>   skip the process and continue. You’ll have to skip two of these
>   prompts in total. After you reach the desktop, Windows 10 will
>   automatically check in with Microsoft and activate itself. You’ll now
>   be running the 64-bit edition of Windows on your PC.
>
> if you want to go back to the 32-bit version of Windows, you’ll need
>   to download the media creation tool — the 64-bit one, if you’re
>   running the 64-bit version of Windows 10 — and use it to create 32-bit
>   installation media. Boot from that installation media and reinstall
>   the 32-bit version over the 64-bit version.

Source [How to Switch From 32-bit Windows 10 to 64-bit Windows 10](http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/)

Comment: Yeah It's x64 bit based

Comment: @NikolaZagorac So you should be good to go. Remember to check everything (64 bit drivers, etc) and backup your important files.

Comment: "Specifically, Windows 10 requires PAE, SSE2, and NX. Microsoft has more information about this here.", could you add the link?

Comment: From the Forbes article [_Microsoft Changes Windows 10 'Free Upgrade' Rules_](http://www.forbes.com/sites/gordonkelly/2015/10/13/microsoft-windows-10-new-upgrade-rules/) it appears that one no longer has to first do an upgrade before doing a clean install in order to get the new version activated.

Comment: @martineau My answer does not say upgrade first. It specifically says "You’ll need to perform a clean install to get to the 64-bit version of Windows 10 from the 32-bit one. There’s no upgrade path."

Comment: @David: You said "First, if you haven’t upgraded to Windows 10 yet, you’ll need to use the upgrade tool to upgrade."

Comment: @martineau Ah, got it. Thanks for the tip. I will read your link a bit later and update the answer if necessary. Note the OP is **already using WIndows 10 32 bit**, so any upgrade (if necessary) does not apply to him anyway.

Comment: @David: Indeed, I think we both missed or forgot that the OP was already running 32-bit Win 10 (that was presumably already activated). A contributing factor for me was the fact that your answer is quite long and it's hard to tell which parts of it is your writing and which are quotes pulled in from some other source.

Comment: @martineau Almost all the answer is quoted directly from http://www.howtogeek.com/228042/how-to-switch-from-32-bit-windows-10-to-64-bit-windows-10/. I've left it complete so it is of more general use (as there is a very small part only that deals with the need to upgrade to Windows 10 first).