# What does Windows 10 Setup do when installing "both" x86 and x64 architectures?

Tags: 64-bit, windows-installation, x86

On a [Running 64 bit programs on a 32 bit system](https://superuser.com/questions/1000858/running-64-bit-programs-on-a-32-bit-system) [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1000862/154126) there's this screenshot:

[image: Windows 10 Setup]

**What does the installer do if you select `Both` as architecture?**

I don' think there's *any* way of having a both x86 **and** x64 system - without it being an x64 system itself. The alternative could be installing two OSes - but I don't see how can a single installer do both and still have a decent UX.

Comment: As I read the link, the selection screen you quote appears during the creation of an installation disc, **not** the installation process itself. It is perfectly possible (and quite common) to have a single installation disc capable of installing either architecture.

Comment: That just creates a universal .ISO

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @mgarciaisaia some folks are just mean. I've up-voted, nothing wrong with the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFH is correct.  This screen is for the Microsoft Windows 10 Media Creation Tool.  It will either prepare an ISO or a USB device with the installation files capable of both the 32bit and 64bit architecture.  Of course if you choose both this will create a larger ISO file or take up more space on your USB device.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10