# i need to install a 64 bit application on my PC which is running a 32 bit OS of windows 7

Tags: windows-7, 32-vs-64-bit

i need to install a 64 bit application on my PC which is running a 32 bit OS of windows 7. my PC is 64 bit capable system. can i install the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can . If u want a 64 bit pc without purchases, make sure you pc support 64 bit.Then download speccy find your serial number and write
It on a page. Then download win 10 media creation tool from microsft. In the setup select 64bit the save it. It will become as iso so you will need to burn it on a DVD. Reboot your pc with the DVD insert then instal it. Then after it will asked u to put a serial number, put the serial number u copy on a page before. Voila u have a win 10 64bit pc

Comment: You can, but it's not recommended. See [Running 64 bit programs on a 32 bit system](http://superuser.com/a/1000863)

Answer (score -2):

The application will need to be ran on a 64 bit OS.

**This will require you to upgrade your OS to a 64 bit version.**

There are alternatives though,  VirtualBox, QEMU, are a few virtual machines which will allow you to run **64bit** applications on a **32bit** host. However, regardless the OS will still need to be a 64bit version install within the Virtual Environment in order to execute 64 bit applications.

Good luck.

Comment: this is not entirely true - If he has a 32-bit OS but a 64bit capable CPU, then you can use a virtual environment such as virtualbox in order to install the application (will need to virtualize the 64bit OS) - If you have a 32bit CPU, then you will need to upgrade the CPU to a 64-bit one and upgrade then OS to 64bit (or keep the 32bit OS and run 64bit in virtual environment)

Comment: Please VTC as a duplicate of [Running 64 bit programs on a 32 bit system](http://superuser.com/q/1000858) (and upvote my answer ;p)

Comment: @MikeDiglio However this will come with a significant speed loss.

Comment: @DavidPostill oh of course, and I wouldn't do it personally, but it is possible, depending on the application

Comment: Trying to understand why this would be potentially downvoted, since it *IS* an acceptable solution. The OS would *NEED* to be 64 bit. Whether or not you're virtualizing 64 bit to do that or not.